# How do I see the difference between two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Table `A` and `B`. Each table has a `barcode` column.

I can join these two on the barcode field. What I want to do is find out which barcodes from table A don't join with B.

For example:

A has:

```
001
002
003
```

B has:

```
001
003
```

I need a query that will pull back 002.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as an anti-join, for which you have three options in MySQL.  In some vague order of preference (most to least):

1. `OUTER JOIN` and `IS NULL`:

   ```
   SELECT A.barcode
   FROM   A LEFT JOIN B USING (barcode)
   WHERE  B.barcode IS NULL
   ```
2. `NOT IN`:

   ```
   SELECT barcode
   FROM   A
   WHERE  barcode NOT IN (
            SELECT barcode
            FROM   B
          )
   ```
3. `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT barcode
   FROM   A
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   B
            WHERE  B.barcode = A.barcode
          )
   ```

See @Quassnoi's blog article, [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) for a comparative analysis of their respective performance.